# Parallel top ten algorithm for distributed data

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

This is an interview question. Suppose there are a few computers and each computer keeps a very large log file of visited URLs. Find the *top ten* most visited URLs.

For example: Suppose there are only 3 computers and we need the *top two* most visited URLs.

```
Computer A: url1, url2, url1, url3
Computer B: url4, url2, url1, url1
Computer C: url3, url4, url1, url3

url1 appears 5 times in all logs
url2 2
url3 3
url4 2 

So the answer is url1, url3
```

The log files are too large to fit in RAM and copy them by network. As I understand, it is important also to make the computation parallel and use all given computers.

How would you solve it?

Comment: Top ten from each computer and then collate as final top 10 can be from a single computer and none from some computers. Start collating from top most from each, stop when you hit number 10.

Comment: @SparKotॐ Are you sure we can take only top ten from each computer and throw away all other URLs? What if the _overall_ top ten contains a URL, which is not in the _local_ top tens

Comment: Oops! I concur with above comment. Nice question +1

Comment: The only way I see is going beyond top 10 on each system; but how far is it necessary to be certain?

Comment: @SparKotॐ I am not sure if I got your question. Anyway ... the answer should be 100% accurate.

Comment: Use map-reduce paradigm.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a pretty standard problem for which there is a well-known solution. You simply sort the log files on each computer by URL and then merge them through a priority queue of size k (the number of items you want) on the "master" computer. This technique has been around since the 1960s, and is still in use today (although slightly modified) in the form of [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

On each computer, extract the URL and the count from the log file, and sort by URL. Because the log files are larger than will fit into memory, you need to do an on-disk merge. That entails reading a chunk of the log file, sorting by URL, writing the chunk to disk. Reading the next chunk, sorting, writing to disk, etc. At some point, you have M log file chunks, each sorted. You can then do an M-way merge. But instead of writing items to disk, you present them, in sorted order (sorted by URL, that is), to the "master".

Each machine sorts its own log.

The "master" computer merges the data from the separate computers and does the top K selection. This is actually two problems, but can be combined into one.

The master creates two priority queues: one for the merge, and one for the top K selection. The first is of size N, where N is the number of computers it's merging data from. The second is of size K: the number of items you want to select. I use a min heap for this, as it's easy and reasonably fast.

To set up the merge queue, initialize the queue and get the first item from each of the "worker" computers. In the pseudo-code below, "get lowest item from merge queue" means getting the root item from the merge queue and then getting the next item from whichever working computer presented that item. So if the queue contains `[1, 2, 3]`, and the items came from computers B, C, A (in that order), then taking the lowest item would mean getting the next item from computer B and adding it to the priority queue.

The master then does the following:

```
working = get lowest item from merge queue
while (items left to merge)
{
    temp = get lowest item from merge queue
    while (temp.url == working.url)
    {
        working.count += temp.count
        temp = get lowest item from merge queue
    }
    // Now have merged counts for one url.
    if (topK.Count < desired_count)
    {
        // topK queue doesn't have enough items yet.
        // so add this one.
        topK.Add(working);
    }
    else if (topK.Peek().count < working.count)
    {
        // the count for this url is larger
        // than the smallest item on the heap
        // replace smallest on the heap with this one
        topK.RemoveRoot()
        topK.Add(working)
    }
    working = temp;
}
// Here you need to check the last item:
if (topK.Peek().count < working.count)
{
    // the count for this url is larger
    // than the smallest item on the heap
    // replace smallest on the heap with this one
    topK.RemoveRoot()
    topK.Add(working)
}
```

At this point, the `topK` queue has the K items with the highest counts.

So each computer has to do a merge sort, which is O(n log n), where `n` is the number of items in that computer's log. The merge on the master is O(n), where `n` is the sum of all the items from the individual computers. Picking the top k items is O(n log k), where `n` is the number of *unique* urls.

The sorts are done in parallel, of course, with each computer preparing its own sorted list. But the "merge" part of the sort is done at the same time the master computer is merging, so there is some coordination, and all machines are involved at that stage.

Comment: Did you make any assumptions with regard to the contents of the log files? You state: *But instead of writing items to disk, you present them, in sorted order (sorted by URL, that is), to the "master".* If the URLs in a log file are all unique, then this basically means that you send the whole file over the the master. But the question states: *The log files are too large to fit in RAM and copy them by network.*

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek: First, we don't send the entire file: just the URL and count. The log file presumably contains much more information. Second, the master has to see the count for every URL, otherwise it can't reliably know the counts. There are some other ways to tackle this (assign ranges of urls to individual machines, for example), but all include a lot of network traffic and more complex communication among the several computers.

Comment: Your presumption on the size of the log file sounds rather random to me. If you think it is valid to say that "The log file presumably contains much more information than just the URLs so we can send all URLs over the network", you might as well state that "The log file presumably contains much more information than just the URLs so we can store all URLs in memory". Yet you go through the lengths of an on-disk merge.

Comment: But... since your answer was accepted and mine was not, I suppose they were fair assumptions after all ;-)

Comment: @Reinier: I suppose so. This is the best solution I know of that will work. I'm still mulling over your suggestion of using some type of hashing scheme to reduce the amount of data communicated over the network. I can *almost* see it working if there are large variations on the number of url references (i.e. some are visited much more often than others). In pathological cases, where the difference between min and max is very small (one or two visits), you'll need a very large number of passes, each with a different hashing algorithm. But there might yet be a way. I need to ponder a bit more.

Comment: There is a flaw in the merging queue. For example, there are 5 computers with their first url as : url1, url2, url3, url2, url3. How could you merge them in the merging queue?

Comment: @maomao: What's the flaw? The algorithm correctly combines the counts for equal urls. That's the whole point of the inner loop (i.e. `while (temp.url == working.url)`). If, after studying the algorithm, you can give me a concrete example that produces an incorrect result, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Given the scale of the log files and the generic nature of the question, this is quite a difficult problem to solve. I do not think that there is one best algorithm for all situations. It depends on the nature of the contents of the log files. For example, take the corner case that all URLs are all unique in all log files. In that case, basically any solution will take a long time to draw that conclusion (if it even gets that far...), and there is not even an answer to your question because there is no top-ten.

I do not have a watertight algorithm that I can present, but I would explore a solution that uses histograms of hash values of the URLs as opposed to the URLs themselves. These histograms can be calculated by means of one-pass file reads, so it can deal with arbitrary size log files. In pseudo-code, I would go for something like this:

- Use a hash function with a limited target space (say 10,000, note that colliding hash-values are expected) to calculate the hash value of each item in the log file and count how many times each of the has value occurs. Communicate the resulting histogram to a server (although it is probably also possible to avoid a central server at all by multicasting the result to every other node -- but I will stick with the more obvious server-approach here)
- The server should merge the histograms and communicate the result back. Depending on the distribution of the URLs, there might be a number of clearly visible peaks already, containing the top-visited URLs.
- Each of the nodes should then focus on the peaks in the histogram. It should go trough its log file again, use an additional hash function (again with a limited target space) to calculate a new hash-histogram for those URLs that have their first hash value in one of the peaks (the number of peaks to focus on would be a parameter to be tuned in the algorithm, depending on the distribution of the URLs), and calculate a second histogram with the new hash values. The result should be communicated to the server.
- The server should merge the results again and analyse the new histogram versus the original histogram. Depending on clearly visible peaks, it might be able to draw conclusions about the two hash values of the top ten URLs already. Or it might have to instruct the machines to calculate more hash values with the second hash function, and probably after that go through a third pass of hash-calculations with yet another hash function. This has to continue until a conclusion can be drawn from the collective group of histograms what the hash values of the peak URLs are, and then the nodes can identify the different URLs from that.

Note that this mechanism will require tuning and optimization with regard to several aspects of the algorithm and hash-functions. It will also need orchestration by the server as to which calculations should be done at any time. It probably will also need to set some boundaries in order to conclude when no conclusion can be drawn, in other words when the "spectrum" of URL hash values is too flat to make it worth the effort to continue calculations.

This approach should work well if there is a clear distribution in the URLs though. I suspect that, practically speaking, the question only makes sense in that case anyway.

Comment: Wow. That's a really complicated and expensive way to produce a result that you can't prove is correct.

Comment: I would not start implementing it until proven that it is correct :-) Why do you say it is expensive? I think the solution requires `O(n)` calculations and much less network traffic than that (with `n` the total number of entries in each file on each node).

Answer (score 1):

Pre-processing: Each computer system processes complete log file and prepares Unique URLs list with count against them.

Getting top URLs:

1. Calculate URL counts at each computer system
2. Collating process at a central system(Virtual)

   - Send URLs with count to a central processing unit one by one in DESC order(i.e from top most)
   - At central system collate incoming URL details
   - Repeat until sum of all the counts from incoming URLs is less than count of Tenth URL in the master list. **A vital step to be absolutely certain**

PS: You'll have top ten URLs across systems not necessarily in that order. To get the actual order you can **reverse collation**. For a given URL on top ten get individual count from dist-computers and form final order.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the conditions below are true:

- You need the top n urls of m hosts.
- You can't store the files in RAM
- There is a master node

I would take the approach below:

Each node reads a portion of the file (ie. MAX urls, where MAX can be, let's say, 1000 urls) and keeps an array arr[MAX]={url,hits}.

When a node has read MAX urls off the file, it sends the list to the master node, and restarts reads until MAX urls is reached again.

When a node reaches the EOF, he sends the remaining list of urls and an EOF flag to the master node.

When the master node receives a list of urls, it compares it with its last list of urls and generates a new, updated one.

When the master node receives the EOF flag from every node and finishes reading his own file, the top n urls of the last version of his list are the ones we're looking for.

<strike>Or</strike>

A different approach that would release the master from doing all the job could be:

Every node reads its file and stores an array same as above, reading until EOF.

When EOF, the node will send the first url of the list and the number of hits to the master.

When the master has collected the first url and number of hits for each node, it generates a list. If the master node has less than n urls, it will ask the nodes to send the second one and so on. Until the master has the n urls sorted.

Comment: If you only send the top URL for each node, the following will not get the max: 4 URLs, 3 PCs, get top 3, counts = `[1,2,0,0], [1,0,2,0], [1,0,0,2]`. The first URL (`1+1+1=3`) is the max, but the master will only receive URLs 2-4 (`2,2,2`).

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's no problem. That's why if the master has not enough urls it will ask for more until the list is completed. However I'm thinking that this option wouldn't work cause one node's third url could be first in a different node and never get to the master... :-(

Answer (score 1):

On each node count the number of occurrences of URL.
Then use a sharding function to distribute the url to another node which owns the key for URL. Now each node will have unique keys.
On Each node then again reduce to get the number occurrences of URLs and then find the top N URLs. Finally send only top N urls to master node which will find the top N URls among K*N items where K is number of node.

```
Eg: K=3
N1 - > url1,url2,url3,url1,url2
N2 - > url2,url4,url1,url5,url2
N3 - > url1,url4,url3,url1,url3
```

Step 1: Count the occurrence per url in each node.

```
 N1 -> (url1,2),(url2,2),(url3,1)
 N2 -> (url4,1),(url2,2),(url5,1),(url1,1)
 N3 -> (url1,2),(url3,2),(url4,1)
```

Step 2: Sharding use hash function(for simplicity, let it be url number % K)

```
 N1 -> (url1,2),(url1,1),(url1,2),(url4,1),(url4,1)
 N2 -> (url2,2),(url2,2),(url5,1)
 N3 -> (url3,2),(url3,1)
```

Step 4: Find the number of occurrences of each key within the node again.

```
N1 -> (url1,5),(url4,2)
N2 -> (url2,4),(url5,1)
N3 -> (url3,3)
```

Step 5: Send only top N to master. Let N=1

```
Master -> (url1,5),(url2,4),(url3,3)
```

Sort the result and get top 1 item which is url1

Step 1 is called map side reduce and it is done to avoid huge shuffle which will occur in Step2.

Answer (score 0):

The below description is the idea for the solution. it is not a pseudocode.
Consider you have a collection of systems.
1.for each A: Collections(systems)
   1.1) Run a daemonA in each computer which probes on the log file for changes.
   1.2) When a change is noticed, wakeup AnalyzerThreadA
   1.3) If AnalyzerThreadA finds a URL using some regex, then update localHashMapA with count++.
      (key = URL, value = count ).
2) Push topTen entries of localHashMapA to ComputerA where AnalyzeAll daemon will be    running.

The above step will be the last step in each system, which will push topTen entries to a master system, say for example: computerA.

3) AnalyzeAll running in computerA will resolve duplicates and update count in masterHashMap of URLs.

4) Print the topTen from masterHashMap.

Comment: What if an URL is in 11 position on all systems and if considered for processing can be in top 3?